# Java 8 for Twitter4J 4.0.3

Tags: java-8, twitter4j

I'm working on a project using Twitter4J and I'm using the latest version (4.0.3).

When using the GET search/tweets endpoint, it takes a long time before I can see the result of my call on the endpoint. So I need to use Java 8 Stream library, so that I can see the result of each endpoint call. Is Twitter4J 4.0.3 already compatible with Java 8?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their official site :

> Twitter4J is featuring:
>
> 100% Pure Java - works on any Java Platform version 5 or later.

So, it will work on Java 8.

> When using the GET search/tweets endpoint, it takes a long time before
> I can see the result of my call on the endpoint.

Since you didn't post your code, but mostly it's might be because of `count` parameter. So, Limit your `count` to 10 or 20 to see the result quickly.